# Angular 6 Port [number] is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, port, angular6

For some reason, I keep getting this error, when trying to fire up my Angular application with ng serve:

"Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port."

I don't know why this is happening, because it was working fine for me last week.

It doesn't matter what number I enter (e.g. ng serve --port xxxx), the same error is showing up, despite that port number not being used.

Changing port numbers is not this issue. Can anyone help me with this, because I'd like to get on with some Angular development?

I've re-installed angular cli globally and it still doesn't work.

I've downgraded to a lower version of Angular CLI and it doesn't work and I've even re-installed Node. Nothing.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I've been searching all day and I can't find anyone with a similar issue.

Please note that I am using windows and not Mac.

Comment: Are you sure that port is not being used? Have you tried running `netstat` to double check?

Comment: Yes, I've ran netstat. It's not being used. None of the port numbers I enter are being used, yet it still says that it is.

Comment: Restarting your PC should also work, make sure the port numbers you are trying are above 3000, try 5200 and let us know

Comment: @RichardPariath I tried 5200 and it's still not working. I am honestly stoked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Turns out that it was my firewall.

The error was misleading because it said the ports I tried were in use, when they weren't.

If anyone gets this error, check the firewall you're using.

Comment: I disabled firewall but still getting error. Can you suggest what to check for in Firewall?

Answer (score -1):

Run this in your terminal `ps aux | grep node`(if you're on a linux flavor machine... most likely that will work) and see what processes come back. If you see an existing node process then you most likely have your application still running in another tab or window (terminal tab or window). Kill the process and run `ng serve`. If all that checks out everything should work.
Cheers.

Comment: Mind editing my answer, with the windows command if you know it? Or adding it in a comment? I can upvote it.

Comment: According to https://serverfault.com/questions/43617/tomcat-wont-start-how-to-check-that-port-8080-is-not-in-use looks like you can use `netstat -ano | findstr 4200`

Comment: The problem is that the port numbers are not in use. I've checked netstat.